# How to delete PostgreSQL database previously created by devcontainer?

Tags: postgresql, vscode-devcontainer

I recently had to delete all Docker containers on my system, and when VSCode rebuilt my Java devcontainer with PostgreSQL, it wouldn't start. I get the following error in the logs:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2023-11-07 20:27:40.074 UTC [1] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2023-11-07 20:27:40.074 UTC [1] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 15, which is not compatible with this version 16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1).
```

I assume this is because the new image is using the database from the old image. Where exactly is this database stored, and how do I get rid of it if it's still there after `docker system prune --all --force --volumes`?

Comment: This is not about getting rid of `a` database it is about trying to install  a new Postgres over an existing Postgres install. You need to uninstall the old Postgres before you install the new one.

Comment: Can you share with us how you're invoking the Docker container?  Are you using `docker-compose` or just `docker run`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: I don't see how this can be an uninstall problem in a Docker container where the previous container and its volumes no longer exist. But OK, so how can I uninstall the older version of PostgreSQL from a Docker container that contains the newer version and won't start?

Comment: @richyen: VSCode uses `docker-compose --project-name my_pet_project_devcontainer -f /home/ytg/projects/my_pet_project/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml -f /home/ytg/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1699369323878.yml -f /home/ytg/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.containerFeatures-1699370322181.yml up -d --no-recreate`

Comment: Thanks -- looks like one of those `.yml` files has a service that uses a `postgres:16` image with a Docker `volume:`.  It might be easier to help you if you can share the contents of `docker-compose.yml` (I'm also curious to know what the other `.yml` files contain.  One way around it is just to switch to a `postgres:15` image, dump, and load into a `postgres:16` image

Comment: If you simply want to delete the data from the volume, I can try to help you identify where it is, but you'll need to share the contents of those `.yml` files first.  Otherwise, if you can afford to work around it, you can use the 3 options that I shared in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a volume that contains a PostgreSQL instance that is compatible with v. 15, but you are trying to load it up with a `postgres:16` image.  This is not possible, as data directories are not immediately compatible with newer versions of Postgres.  Even without Docker, moving from an older database instance/cluster to a newer database binary requires either 1) dump/reload or 2) use of `pg_upgrade`.  Some options below:

### Option 0: Find and delete the data cluster

You mentioned that you have 3 `.yml` files -- you'll need to look under the `volumes:` section of the service corresponding to `postgres:##`.  Without knowing the actual directory mapping, I cannot 100% help you.  However, since we know that you did `docker system prune --all --force --volumes` and the data is still there, then we know that the data you're trying to overwrite is not in a Docker Volume, but probably some directory mapping to your host machine.  Once you identify which directory that is, you can either 1) delete the mapping from the `.yml` file or 2) delete the contents of the mapped folder

### Option 1: stick with Postgres 15

The work around the issue quickly, just change from using a `postgres:16` image to a `postgres:15` image in your `docker-compose.yml` file

### Option 2: Use Postgres 15 to dump, then reload to Postgres 16

Using a `postgres:15` image to call `pg_dump` against the database cluster will result in a logical/plaintext dump of your database.  With this dump, you can start up a `postgres:16` image with a new Docker Volume, and then use `psql` to copy the contents of the dump into the new database

### Option 3: Use pg_upgrade to perform the upgrade against the cluster

Note: This is a lot more complex, and requires a bit of advanced knowledge of how the containers work.

To use `pg_upgrade`, you'll need to use a `postgres:15` image (preferably running on a Debian/Ubuntu underlying OS).  You'll need to use `apt` to install Postgres 16, and then use `pg_upgrade` to upgrade the data directory.  After that, you can tear down the container, and use a `postgres:16` container to access and serve up the now-updated data cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Apparently, even though I pruned the volumes, the volume was still there for some reason. I don't know why. Manually running a `docker volume rm` on it eventually worked, but otherwise I probably would've gone with your dump and reload solution.

Comment: Ah, glad the `docker volume rm` worked.  It could've been the case that `docker volume prune` didn't work because the volume may be linked to another container